Does Firestore Query with range and inequality filters on multiple fields still require Composite Index?
I saw the news that Firestore is now allowing inequality filters on multiple fields but my question if you still need to create a composite index at a collection level in order to do this? Previously it was the case that you could do inequality filters on multiple fields by creating a composite index at a collection level so has this changed?
When trying using the modular API I am still getting the error message that I need to create a composite index at the collection level.
In my scenario the collection name is unique to each user so I cannot create composite indexes.
Update: importing using url 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-firestore.js'
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, getFirestore } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.0/firebase-firestore.js'

As far as I know, the new feature doesn't change anything about what indexes are required - it "just" uses then differently. From the description it sounds like you've already discovered the answer yourself: yes, you need to add an index for each specific field combination you want to query.

@FrankvanPuffelen okay thank you. That was what I figured but I thought perhaps there was a beta version of the SDK I needed to be using.

As far as I know, the new feature doesn't change anything about what indexes are required - it "just" uses then differently.
From the description it sounds like you've already discovered the answer yourself: yes, you need to add an index for each specific field combination you want to query.
